# RecyclerView is loading only the first element

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a demo of a TikTok-like application, in which I'm making use of a RecyclerView with a PagerSnapHelper. I would like to optimize the loading of the videos, so that when I swipe vertically, the next video is already loaded, but waiting. For this my idea was to have the ExoPlayer instances in memory and always load the current video and the next one leave it paused, but I can not do this with RecyclerView, since debugging the code, I have seen that when it loads for the first time, only loads the first element, but not the next, and when I swipe and if I load the current and the next one.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IExoPlayerInstances {

    companion object {
        private const val JSON_CLIPS = "clips.json"
    }

    private val exoInstances = mutableListOf<ExoInstance>()
    private var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)
        val clips = getTrainingClipsFromJson()
        initClipsRecycler(clips)
    }

    private fun initClipsRecycler(clipInstances: ClipInstances) {
        val pageSnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
        val clipsAdapter = ClipsAdapter(this)
        binding?.mainListClips?.adapter = clipsAdapter
        pageSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding?.mainListClips)
        clipsAdapter.submitList(clipInstances.clips)
    }

    private fun getTrainingClipsFromJson(): ClipInstances {
        val json = assets?.open(JSON_CLIPS)
            ?.bufferedReader()
            .use { it?.readText() }
        return Gson().fromJson(json, ClipInstances::class.java)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        binding = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun getExoPlayerInstances(exoPlayer: ExoPlayer, position: Int) {
        val exoInstance = ExoInstance(position, exoPlayer)
        exoInstances.add(exoInstance)
        Log.i("EXO_INSTANCES", "Número de elementos: ${exoInstances.size}")
    }
}
```

This is my activity, in which I have implemented an interface that is used in the adapter, in this way I have discovered this behavior. I put the adapter below:

```kotlin
class ClipsAdapter(private val exoPlayerInstances: IExoPlayerInstances) :
    ListAdapter<ClipInstance, ClipsViewHolder>(ClipsDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ClipsViewHolder {
        val binding = ClipRowBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ClipsViewHolder(exoPlayerInstances, binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ClipsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
    }
}

class ClipsViewHolder(
    private val exoPlayerInstances: IExoPlayerInstances,
    private val binding: ClipRowBinding,
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(exoInstance: ClipInstance) {
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(binding.root.context).build()

        binding.rowLabelTitle.text = exoInstance.title

        exoPlayerInstances.getExoPlayerInstances(exoPlayer, absoluteAdapterPosition)
    }
}

class ClipsDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ClipInstance>() {

    // region override methods

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ClipInstance, newItem: ClipInstance): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ClipInstance, newItem: ClipInstance): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

    // endregion
}
```

Here as you can see I am creating an instance of ExoPlayer each time a new holder is painted, but I have the problem that the first time the next one is not being painted, only that one. I don't want help to make the logic, I just want to know how I could load the next element, that there are always two (or as many as I want) in memory.

Comment: Have you tried using the ViewPager2 component and the setOffscreenPageLimit(num) function yet ? https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but the way a `RecyclerView` works is it inflates a pool of `ViewHolder`s and reuses those to display data (passing the VH to `onBindViewHolder` so you can configure it).

So your `ViewHolder` class should contain its own instance of the video player, created when the VH is constructed. That way it's created **once** (per ViewHolder instance), and all the initial heavy setup (like inflating/finding views and creating other components) is taken care of up-front. So `onBindViewHolder` (called whenever a new item needs to be displayed) just needs to set stuff on the VH, nothing heavy like creating new instances of stuff. This keeps the list nice and responsive when you scroll it!

Calling `ExoPlayer.Builder().build()` in `onBindViewHolder` (through your `bind` function in the VH) means that as you scroll the list, it's constantly creating builders and media players, which is slow and uses a lot of system resources. It doesn't fit the idea of setting up a `ViewHolder` as a *thing that displays an item* and then reusing (recycling) it, y'know?

---

So what you probably want is something like this:

```
class ClipsViewHolder(
    private val binding: ClipRowBinding,
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    // each ViewHolder has its own player instance
    private val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(binding.root.context).build()

    // set it on the player view in the VH's layout
    init {
        binding.playerView.setPlayer(player)
    }

    fun bind(clip: Clip) {
        binding.rowLabelTitle.text = clip.title
        // prepare the clip
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(clip.uri)
        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        player.prepare()
    }
}
```

(I'm assuming you have some data source with the video URI etc.)

So this way, when `onBindViewHolder` is called by the `RecyclerView`, it sets the new clip URI on the player, and prepares it. `onBindViewHolder` is called for ViewHolders that are just out of view, so they're ready to display if the list is scrolled, so this should prepare the videos after (and before) the current video. You could look at [`setItemCacheViewSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#setItemViewCacheSize(int)) to tweak the size of the pool of offscreen items, maybe [`setRecycledViewPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#setRecycledViewPool(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool)) if you need more control over that.

I know that's fairly different to what you have now, but I'm not really sure why you have a collection of player instances in the adapter and the Activity. But what you're doing in the adapter right now (creating new players on scroll, i.e. through `onBindViewHolder`) is not best practice